# Twitter Search API – since_id and max_id

Tags: node.js, twitter

How should I calculate `since_id` and `max_id` when I want to use Twitter's `search` API?
I want to collect a lot of data from today 00:00:00 until 23:59:59 today. So I read I have to use `max_id` and `since_id` as pagination doesn't exist anymore. How would I use it in the public/worldwide search function?

I want to gather **all** tweets from today with a certain set of hashtags. How should I go about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the twitter search API. Your arguments would have the following structure:

```
#yourtag since:2015-04-27 until:2015-04-28
```

If you're using the npm module:

```
client.get('search/tweets', {q: '#yourtag since:2015-04-27 until:2015-04-28'}, function(error, tweets, response){
   console.log(tweets);
});
```

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search

Comment: Alright, I have. Then I have the next point:
There are like millions of results, because I'm not loading a timeline.

I thought about using `result_type = recent` because it would simply grabbing the latest tweet's id. How would I go about doing this without hitting the rate limit?

Comment: Millions of results? If your use case exceeds twitter's free API rate limit you might need to consider a more analytics-flavored service like https://gnip.com